# JavaScript parseInt on hover?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple multiplier

```
function addFive() {
 document.getElementById("amount").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value) +5;
}

<span id="5" onclick="addFive()">+5</span>
```

I would like it to function as when you mouseover it prints into the selected area, instead of clicking. I've tried replacing onclick with mouseover without luck.

Is this possible with JavaScript, what I'm I looking for?

Comment: show more code how you catch the event

Comment: `onmouseover` or `addEventListener('mouseover', fn);`

Comment: Thank you very much Shilly, that did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than including the javascript event listener inline, you might try deploying javascript *unobtrusively* instead.

The *unobtrusive javascript* approach separates more cleanly the **structure** of the document and the **behaviour** of the document.

```
<span id="span5">+5</span>

<script>

var span5 = document.getElementById('span5');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');

function addFive() {
    amount.value += 5;
}

span5.addEventListener('mouseover',addFive,false);

</script>
```

Comment: I agree. And to add to your answer @Rounin, using a library like JQuery or a framework like Angular will help make your code more maintainable and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do it look through the documentation or search for the event you're trying to listen for. This is what you need

```
<span id="5" onmouseover="addfive()">+5</span>
```